# php if condition syntax error

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

I have these code:

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while (true):
   echo "test";
   $i<4 ? $i++ : break;
endwhile; 
?>
```

error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BREAK in C:\xampp\htdocs\data\index.php on line 5

there is a syntax error with the if condition, I can really make out what. can anybody help. thanks a lot.

Comment: This is what happens when people get told that `? :` is "just like if-else"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator is used for assignment or to return a value. You cannot place `break` in the `else (:)` case of a ternary operation.

```
// Assignment
$x = $i<4 ? $i : 0;
// For a value returned into a function argument $i or 0
do_something($i<4 ? $i : 0);
```

It cannot be used for a regular `else` case containing a language construct as you're doing with `break`.  Instead use a regular `if()`

```
$i = 0;
while (true):
  if ($i<4) {
    $i++
  }
  else {
    break;
  }
endwhile;
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, you had inconsistent bracing in the if else.

Comment: I think that it is not obligatory to use the returned value of the ternary expression. Therefore, it could be used as a standalone statement.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the ternary operator is like that:

```
ternary_expression ::= boolean_expression ? expression : expression
```

The problem with your example is that `break` is not an expression but a statement. Your syntax could work if you had an expression instead, although it would seem awkward. I would suggest a normal `if` in any case.